# My Australian student visa was refused and subsequently my New Zealand student visa was refused

Tags: student-visa

My New Zealand student visa was refused due to poor knowledge of my course. If I first apply for a foundation course in that field, then what are my chances for visa approval with New Zealand?

Comment: What is field of study?

Comment: I applied in information technology but now I want to apply in accounting because my background is belong to accounting.

Comment: I ve had an australian visa rejection in the past and now I am thinking to apply to new zealand on a different course
Did you mention about your previous visa refusals?

Answer (score 2):

Work to improve your knowledge of the field that wish to study in a demonstrable way. Not only should you be able to demonstrate that knowledge with obvious understanding on your own part, you should even be able to provide evidence that other credible sources verify your accomplishment. Then apply again.